# How to call MongoDB CRUD operations from outside of the async run function | JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, crud

The following code is the default async run function for the MongoDB JS driver.

```js
async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db('sample_mflix');
    const movies = database.collection('movies');
    // Query for a movie that has the title 'Back to the Future'
    const query = { title: 'Back to the Future' };
    const movie = await movies.findOne(query);
    console.log(movie);
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Is there any way on earth to do the CRUD operations etc outside of that function, e.g in an expressjs endpoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function that connects to the DB, probably in a different file and `export` the function

```
// DB.js
async function connectToDatabase() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    return client.db('sample_mflix');
  } catch(err) {
    console.dir(err);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

Then `import` it if you're using the `export` method, or just call the function

```
app.get('/api/path', () => {
  const db = await connectToDatabse();

  if (db) {
    const query = {
      title: 'Back to the Future'
    };

    const movie = await db.collection('movies').findOne(query);
    console.log(movie)
  }
})
```